# How to bind DataGridView with two tables, and perform CRUD operation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Here are my table structures:

First table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblToolModification_Pramary]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReportNo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ToolModificationDate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductionDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DrawingNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DIENo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NoOfCavity] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DIEMakerCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DIEMakerName] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblToolModification_Pramary] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReportNo] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblToolModification_Foreign]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReportNo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SrlNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DrawingDimension] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RequiredDimension] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ActualInDie] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ActionInNeeded] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ResultModification] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblToolModification_Foriegn] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is my design:

```
<Window x:Class="demo.Foundry.Sample.Tool_Modification_View"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:shell="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/shell"
        xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        Icon="/img\F_Logo.png"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        Title="Tool Modification View"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Height="692"
        Width="1591.9"
        Background="#d9f9f7"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-45">
        <Label Content="Tool Modification View"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Height="25"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
               Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" />
        <Grid Margin="10,30,4,29">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Fill="DarkGreen"
                       Height="50"
                       Margin="61,0,0,0"
                       Stroke="Black"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Width="1163" />
            <Label Content="Tool Modification View"
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="575,11,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="155"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.03,0.423"
                   Height="27" />
            <DataGrid Name="dgDIE_Outward_DC"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="61,50,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Width="1163"
                      Height="310"
                      AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ReportNo, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="80"
                                        Header="Report No"
                                        IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ToolModificationDate, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="80"
                                        Header="Date" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SrlNo, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="50"
                                        Header="Sr.No" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductCode, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="80"
                                        Header="Product" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductionDescription, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Header="Description" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DrawingNo, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="100"
                                        Header="Drawing" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DIENo, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="55"
                                        Header="DIE No." />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NoOfCavity, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="55"
                                        Header="Cavity" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DIEMakerName, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="100"
                                        Header="Vendor Name" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DrawingDimension, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Header="Drawing Dimension" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RequiredDimension, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Header="Required Dimension" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ActualInDie, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Header="Actual In DIE" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ActionInNeeded, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Header="Action Needed" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ResultModification, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Width="200"
                                        Header="Result After Modification" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Fill="Beige"
                       Height="50"
                       Margin="62,356,0,0"
                       Stroke="Black"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Width="1163" />
            <Label  Content="Report No."
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="62,365,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="1.639,0.468"
                    Width="65" />
            <ComboBox TabIndex="6"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="127,365,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Width="150"
                      Height="28"
                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,1.094" />
            <Label  Content="Product"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="277,365,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="1.639,0.468"
                    Width="65" />
            <ComboBox TabIndex="6"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="331,365,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Width="150"
                      Height="28"
                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,1.094" />
            <Label  Content="Drawing"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="495,365,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="1.639,0.468"
                    Width="65" />
            <ComboBox TabIndex="6"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="550,366,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Width="150"
                      Height="28"
                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.474,1.094" />
            <Button Name="btnExit"
                    Content="Exit"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="843,360,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="231"
                    Click="btnExit_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want CRUD operation in this `DataGridView` - how do I implement that? Please help..

All operation should perform within this datagridview delete operation perform when we click keyboard delete button . edit and insert operation perform within datagridview column

Comment: right now i m not be able to bind datagridview with two tables

Comment: i dont  have any idea how it will perform

Comment: You wont be able to bind it to 2 tables at once. You would need to either rethink your database design or you would need to bring the 2 tables in as a single query, possibly using a union.

Comment: i had did binding for only one table

Comment: So if your binding worked for one table then what is your question?

Comment: how to write query could u plz share..

Comment: my question is bind two table record in one datagridview

Comment: You would need to use union syntax, basic idea is:

select col1,col2,col3 from table1
union all
select col4,col5,col6 from table 2

If you need more info read here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: select MP.*,MF.* from tblToolModification_Pramary MP inner Join tblToolModification_Foreign MF on MP.ReportNo=MF.ReportNo

Comment: this is query and it will work

Comment: by the way  Thanx  Christopher Trevor

Comment: I moved my comment out to an answer, please accept that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to bind it to 2 tables at once. You would need to either rethink your database design or you would need to bring the 2 tables in as a single query, possibly using a union.